# argument to nativeprocess failed

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I need to pass the "" to the mm.exe that run with nativeprocess. When I pass **"In From MIDI Yoke:  1"** even using **\"** to the nativeprocess, it won't launch the application properly and caused it to crash. What wrong this the code?

```
private function soundbank():void {
                var argMidi5:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
                var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("java/mm.exe");
                argMidi5.push('-g 0 -m winmidi -o midi.winmidi.device="In From MIDI Yoke:  1"');

                npSB = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                npSB.workingDirectory = File.applicationDirectory;
                direct = String(File.applicationDirectory);
                npSB.executable = file;

                npSB.arguments = argMidi5;
                npSBOut = new NativeProcess();
                npSBOut.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onSoundbank);
                npSBOut.start(npSB);
                trace(argMidi5);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
argMidi5.push("-g");
argMidi5.push("0");
argMidi5.push("-m");
argMidi5.push("winmidi");
argMidi5.push("-o");
argMidi5.push("midi.winmidi.device=\"In From MIDI Yoke:  1\"");
```

Comment: It won't accept, so I have manage to solve it without the double quote for after the "="

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are passed as individual strings in a vector, not a single string.

Comment: So what is the solution? The application require "", without it, it won't work.